# "Access denied for user '…'" when I didn't provide a username for the database

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error while trying to run a python application that uses the following regex entry

```
database:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    name: 
    password:
    port: 3306
    user:
```

I am getting the following error on console.log when I am trying to run the application using the database.

```
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'ahmed'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I am pretty new to command line based MySQL and ubuntu itself

Answer (score 0):

If we fail to provide a username and password to the MySQL dialect then the drivers (mysqldb and pymysql, at least) attempt to log into the MySQL server without a password using the current username from the OS.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(
    sa.engine.URL.create(
        "mysql+pymysql",
        host="192.168.0.199",
        database="test",
    )
)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    """
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) 
    (1045, "Access denied for user 'gord'@'192.168.0.179' (using password: NO)")
    """
```

You will either need to provide SQLAlchemy with a valid username and password for the MySQL server, or create a MySQL user named "ahmed" without a password that has permission to access the database for your application.

Comment: The configs for MySQL are in the yaml file which I pasted what username and password should I provide? Is there any command to remove that privileges or give it to the logged in user which is Ahmed (me) the only user of my os Ubuntu?